# Counting independent components of the Riemann curvature tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, spacetime-dimensions, degrees-of-freedom

In 4D spacetime, we may choose a locally inertial frame at point P, that is we always have a transformation such that $g_{{\mu'}{\nu'}}(P) = \eta_{{\mu'}{\nu'}}$ and its first derivatives vanish. However, 20 second derivatives cannot be made to vanish. My question is, if we did this in an $n$-dimensional spacetime, how many second derivatives cannot be made to vanish? I know this counts the number of independent components of the Riemann curvature tensor. I know a similar question is [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80166/), and that they get $n^2 (n^2-1) / 12$, but I'm not sure where this comes from?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The $n^2(n^2-1)/12$ comes from the symmetries of the Riemann tensor and the algebraic Bianchi identity.

$R_{abcd}$ is antisymmetric in $ab$ and in $cd$. This means that these pairs of indices can take

$$m=\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

different values. For example, for $n=4$, they take the values $01,02,03,12,13,23$; for other values like $11$, the component is zero.

$R_{abcd}$ is also symmetric when you swap $ab$ with $cd$. This means that, if we didn't take the algebraic Bianchi identity into account, there would be

$$\frac{m(m+1)}{2}=\frac{n^4-2n^3+3n^2-2n}{8}$$

independent components. For $n=4$, there are 21 of them:

$$0101, 0102, 0103, 0112, 0113, 0123$$
$$0202, 0203, 0212, 0213, 0223$$
$$0303, 0312, 0313, 0323$$
$$1212, 1213, 1223$$
$$1313, 1323$$
$$2323$$

Finally, the algebraic Bianchi identity,

$$R_{abcd}+R_{acdb}+R_{adbc}=0$$

provides

$$\binom{n}{4}=\frac{n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n}{24}$$

relationships between these components. (In this identity, the indices must be all different; otherwise, it reduces to the previous symmetry and antisymmetry relations. So we're choosing 4 indices out of $n$.) Subtracting off this number reduces the number of independent components to

$$\frac{n^4-2n^3+3n^2-2n}{8}-\frac{n^4-6n^3+11n^2-6n}{24}=\frac{n^4-n^2}{12}=\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}.$$

Summarizing this argument, the number of independent components is

$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}\left[\binom{n}{2}+1\right]-\binom{n}{4}=\frac{n^2(n^2-1)}{12}.$$

Here is a table of the number of independent components of the Riemann tensor for various dimensions up to 26, the maximum that I think physicists care about:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & 0 \\
 2 & 1 \\
 3 & 6 \\
 4 & 20 \\
 5 & 50 \\
 6 & 105 \\
 7 & 196 \\
 8 & 336 \\
 9 & 540 \\
 10 & 825 \\
 11 & 1210 \\
 12 & 1716 \\
 13 & 2366 \\
 14 & 3185 \\
 15 & 4200 \\
 16 & 5440 \\
 17 & 6936 \\
 18 & 8721 \\
 19 & 10830 \\
 20 & 13300 \\
 21 & 16170 \\
 22 & 19481 \\
 23 & 23276 \\
 24 & 27600 \\
 25 & 32500 \\
 26 & 38025 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Fantastic solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer. The part I don't get: why can just deduce the number obtained using Bianchi identity from the previous result? Asked a question here about that topic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060075/how-to-take-algebraic-bianchi-identity-into-account-when-calculating-the-number

Comment: How did the (m+1) term come? I can't understand why it is (m+1) and not m

Comment: @Igris Once you see the symmetry between lower index pairs $ab$ and $cd$ you can treat the tensor as a symmetric matrix of dimension $m$ calculated earlier. So treat $ab$ as $i$ and $cd$ as $j$ and imagine it's in fact $R_{ij}$ now. To count the independent components of this symmetric $m \times m$ matrix means simply to sum an arithemtic series from $1$ to $m$ which is indeed $\frac{m(m+1)}{2}$. Hope this helps.